# In C, what exactly does something like "a string"[4] mean and signify?

Tags: c, arrays, string, indexing

The following is taken from the C book by Mike Banahan [(Link: Section 2.8.1.5)](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter2/expressions_and_arithmetic.html)

I understand that `"a string"` reduces to a pointer to the first character of that string which is stored somewhere in memory. But I am clueless about `"a string"[4]` and what's given in the book is a bit unclear to me.

How can the size be 4 when the string has 9 characters? Beyond that, would `"a string"[0]` refer to the first character, `"a string"[2]` to third character, and so on?  If not, can you please explain in simple term what that syntax of the book means?

The line that's killing me is **"The first results in an**
**expression whose type is char and whose value is the internal**
 **representation of the letter ‘r’ "**. Where does 'r' come in?

Here's the text taken from that book:

> Strings are implemented as arrays and although it might look odd, it
>   is entirely permissible to use array indexing on them:

```
 -  "a string"[4]
 -   L"a string"[4]
```

> are both valid expressions. The first results in an
>   expression whose type is char and whose value is the internal
>   representation of the letter ‘r’ (remember arrays index from zero, not
>   one). The second has the type wchar_t and also has the value of the
>   internal representation of the letter ‘r’.

NB: Please ignore the stuff about the wide character part as I feel that's not relevant. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can spell out `"a string"[4]` as follows:

```
char *s = "a string";
char ch = s[4];
```

Does it make things clearer?

```
s[0]: a
s[1]:  
s[2]: s
s[3]: t
s[4]: r
s[5]: i
s[6]: n
s[7]: g
s[8]: \0
```

Comment: @PavelŠimerda Done. Actually I wait for some hours by default before accepting an answer as the best. On SO, you never know when someone other of NPE's caliber can come up with an answer better than an already perfect answer :-)

Comment: @Thokchom: Ah sure, I haven't yet got to the level of asking a question that wouldn't be voted down or even closed ;). So I'm rather trying to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The string literal `"a string"` signifies that it is a **pointer to the first character** of string `"a string"`. C allows pointers to be subscripted, so a string literal can be subscripted.

Therefore  `"a string"[4]` will give the 5<sup>th</sup> character `r`.